# Simple object persist in Spring + hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jakarta-ee, jpa

I suppose it is not standard way of doing that so any tips will be helpful, here is my code:

```
@RequestMapping("/register")
public String register(Map<String, Object> map, @ModelAttribute("user") MyUser user) {

    if(user.getLogin() == ""){
        map.put("user", new MyUser());
    }
    else{
        map.put("user", user);
        map.put("result", userService.addMyUser(user));
    }

    return "register";
}
```

what cause following error:

> org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null id in org.mypackage.MyUser entry
>   (don't flush the Session after an exception occurs)

Here is `MyUser` class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MyUser")
public class MyUser{

    @Id
    @Column(name="idMyUser")
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name="login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

}
```

Comment: Please provide the entity-class for MyUser, sounds like you could be missing @GeneratedValue in the primary key-field ('@Id'), in which case you'd need to set it manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the strategy and/or generator for the @GeneratedValue, see [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GeneratedValue.html) and [here](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/GenerationType.html) for details (for example, you could try `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)`. You could also check if your database table is set to generate the primary key values. The exception seems to indicate that the primary key -field is left unset by the current strategy and/or generator.

Comment: Thanks, I actually hasn't got "Auto increment" on my id field in DB. But how could I prevent save my user when form is empty? (in case when user just enter first time in `register` page)? I noticed that `if` condition get false...

Comment: Did you get the primary key problem solved though? I haven't ever tried using Hibernate/JPA without database-generated primary keys, you might need to set them manually. As for the condition failing, don't use '==' -comparison with Strings (or with any non-primitive types in general), this will check if the two objects are the same object, not if their contents are equal. So use 'if(user.getLogin().equals(""))' instead.

Comment: Well, shortly: now I have problem with `if` condition, it always go to `else` clause, I don't know what condition there sould be...